How to make CDI work in JerseyTest with Jakarta EE?
This setup works fine when running in Glassfish, but I get errors when running tests.
My setup is this:
UserRepository.java:

@ApplicationScoped
public class UserRepository {
  @Inject
   private EntityManager em;
    //private EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("default");
    @Transactional
    public User create(User user) throws Exception {
        //EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

        try {
          //  em.getTransaction().begin();
            em.persist(user);
            em.flush();
            //em.getTransaction().commit();
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
        return user;
    }

    public List<User> findAll() throws Exception {
        //EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        try {
            CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
            CriteriaQuery<User> cq = cb.createQuery(User.class);
            Root<User> root = cq.from(User.class);
            cq.select(root);
            return em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
    }

}


UserResource.java:

@Path("/users")
public class UserResource {
    @Inject
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getUsers() {
        try {
            List<User> users = userRepository.findAll();
            return Response.ok(users).build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                    .entity("Error retrieving users: " + e.getMessage())
                    .build();
        }
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response addUser(User user) {
        try {
            userRepository.create(user);
            return Response.status(Response.Status.CREATED)
                    .entity("user created")
                    //.location(URI.create("/users/" + newUser.getId()))
                    .build();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                    .entity("Error creating user: " + e.getMessage())
                    .build();
        }
    }




Resources.java:

@ApplicationScoped
public class Resources {
    @PersistenceUnit(unitName = "default")
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @Produces
    @Default
    public EntityManager create() {
        return this.entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    }

    public void dispose(@Disposes @Default EntityManager entityManager) {
        if (entityManager.isOpen()) {
            entityManager.close();
        }
    }
}


persistence.xml for test (which Im not sure is found):
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persistence xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_3_0.xsd"
             version="3.0">
    <persistence-unit name="default" transaction-type="JTA">


        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:/comp/env/jdbc/TestDB</jta-data-source>
        <class>org.example.demo.entity.User</class>


        <properties>
            <!-- Hibernate specific properties -->
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>

            <!-- För utvecklingsläge -->

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>


UserResource.java
@EnableAutoWeld
@ExtendWith(WeldJunit5Extension.class)
public class UserResourceTest extends JerseyTest {

    @Inject
    UserRepository userRepository;

    public User saveAUser() {
      UserRepository userRepository = CDI.current().select(UserRepository.class).get();
        User user = new User("Håkan", "Gleissman", 55);
        try {
            userRepository.create(user);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return user;


    }
    @Override
    protected Application configure() {
        forceSet(TestProperties.CONTAINER_PORT, "0");
        return new ResourceConfig(UserResource.class);


    }
    @Test
    public void testGetUsers(){
        //System.setProperty("javax.persistence.Persistence", "META-INF/persistence.xml");
        saveAUser();
        Response response = target("/users").request().get();
        List<User> users = response.readEntity(new GenericType<List<User>>() {});
        System.out.println("Listans storlek: " + users.size());
        for (User user : users) {
            System.out.println(user);
        }
        assertEquals(200, response.getStatus());
        assertEquals(1, users.size());
    }

pom.xml dependencies:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>9.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.224</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-junit5</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.Final</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Weld Core (for CDI in SE environment) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld.se</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-se-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-cdi2-se</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.el-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.el</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

Im trying to run a test, but it seems CDI is not working in test environment. Either the error complains about my UserRepository or the EntityManager.
This is my current error, whichs is thrown when executing the line:
UserRepository userRepository = CDI.current().select(UserRepository.class).get();


Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:62510', transport: 'socket'
aug. 30, 2024 1:18:06 EM org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup <clinit>
INFO: WELD-000900: 4.0.2 (Final)
aug. 30, 2024 1:18:06 EM org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup startContainer
INFO: WELD-000101: Transactional services not available. Injection of @Inject UserTransaction not available. Transactional observers will be invoked synchronously.
aug. 30, 2024 1:18:06 EM org.jboss.weld.event.ExtensionObserverMethodImpl checkRequiredTypeAnnotations
INFO: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] org.jboss.weld.junit5.auto.TestInstanceInjectionExtension.rewriteTestClassScope(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<T>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
aug. 30, 2024 1:18:06 EM org.jboss.weld.environment.se.WeldContainer fireContainerInitializedEvent
INFO: WELD-ENV-002003: Weld SE container ace65ccb-c2de-4cc1-95c5-2ec6edbf8f13 initialized
aug. 30, 2024 1:18:06 EM org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup startContainer
INFO: WELD-000101: Transactional services not available. Injection of @Inject UserTransaction not available. Transactional observers will be invoked synchronously.
aug. 30, 2024 1:18:06 EM org.jboss.weld.environment.se.WeldContainer fireContainerInitializedEvent
INFO: WELD-ENV-002003: Weld SE container c3e05aa4-b37f-4569-b136-5c6e6ab7d237 initialized
aug. 30, 2024 1:18:06 EM org.glassfish.jersey.test.grizzly.GrizzlyTestContainerFactory$GrizzlyTestContainer <init>
INFO: Creating GrizzlyTestContainer configured at the base URI http://localhost:<AVAILABLE-PORT>/
aug. 30, 2024 1:18:06 EM org.jboss.weld.environment.deployment.discovery.DiscoveryStrategyFactory create
INFO: WELD-ENV-000020: Using jandex for bean discovery
aug. 30, 2024 1:18:07 EM org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup startContainer
INFO: WELD-000101: Transactional services not available. Injection of @Inject UserTransaction not available. Transactional observers will be invoked synchronously.
aug. 30, 2024 1:18:07 EM org.jboss.weld.environment.se.WeldContainer fireContainerInitializedEvent
INFO: WELD-ENV-002003: Weld SE container aac9ce54-dc96-4c99-a924-d29ae3102c2c initialized
aug. 30, 2024 1:18:07 EM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.NetworkListener start
INFO: Started listener bound to [localhost:62514]
aug. 30, 2024 1:18:07 EM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer start
INFO: [HttpServer] Started.
aug. 30, 2024 1:18:07 EM org.glassfish.jersey.test.grizzly.GrizzlyTestContainerFactory$GrizzlyTestContainer start
INFO: Started GrizzlyTestContainer at the base URI http://localhost:62514/
aug. 30, 2024 1:18:07 EM org.jboss.weld.environment.se.WeldSEProvider getCDI
INFO: WELD-ENV-002006: Multiple containers running - CDI.current() may not work properly: [ace65ccb-c2de-4cc1-95c5-2ec6edbf8f13, c3e05aa4-b37f-4569-b136-5c6e6ab7d237, aac9ce54-dc96-4c99-a924-d29ae3102c2c]
aug. 30, 2024 1:18:07 EM org.jboss.weld.environment.se.WeldSEProvider getCDI
INFO: WELD-ENV-002006: Multiple containers running - CDI.current() may not work properly: [ace65ccb-c2de-4cc1-95c5-2ec6edbf8f13, c3e05aa4-b37f-4569-b136-5c6e6ab7d237, aac9ce54-dc96-4c99-a924-d29ae3102c2c]
aug. 30, 2024 1:18:07 EM org.jboss.weld.environment.se.WeldContainer shutdown
INFO: WELD-ENV-002001: Weld SE container aac9ce54-dc96-4c99-a924-d29ae3102c2c shut down
aug. 30, 2024 1:18:07 EM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.NetworkListener shutdownNow
INFO: Stopped listener bound to [localhost:62514]
aug. 30, 2024 1:18:07 EM org.jboss.weld.environment.se.WeldContainer shutdown
INFO: WELD-ENV-002001: Weld SE container c3e05aa4-b37f-4569-b136-5c6e6ab7d237 shut down

org.jboss.weld.exceptions.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: WELD-001334: Unsatisfied dependencies for type UserRepository with qualifiers ...


Can you be more specific about the error? Can you provide the full stack trace and whether it happens when JUnit is starting the test, on line CDI.current().select(UserRepository.class).get() or else?

Hi and thank you for responding. I added the current stack trace.

I removed the Injection of the UserRepository in the test before getting this error.
